# Adding Google Maps to a directions navigation link on a website

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, navigation

I am creating a website for a school project and I have to have some navigation links and one of them is directions to the location the website is for. My link is not currently active. How do I make it a clickable link and have the address and a google map link on the directions link, once its clicked?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Hope this helps you

Open Google Maps.
Go to the directions, map, or Street View image you'd like to embed.
In the top left, click Menu Menu.
Click Share or embed map.
Click Embed map.
To the left of the text box, pick the size you want by clicking the Down arrow Down Arrow.
Copy the text in the box. Paste it into the HTML of your website or blog.